# removing spaces outside quotes in r

Tags: r

Rearranging simpsons names with R to follow first name, last name format but there are large spaces between the names, is it possible to remove spaces outside the quoted names?

```
library(stringr)

simpsons <- c("Moe Syzlak", "Burns, C. Montgomery", "Rev. Timothy Lovejoy", "Ned Flanders", "Simpson, Homer", "Dr. Julius Hibbert")

reorder <- sapply(sapply(str_split(simpsons, ","), str_trim),rev)

for (i in 1:length(name) ) {
    splitname[i]<- paste(unlist(splitname[i]), collapse = " ")
}

splitname <- unlist(splitname)
```

Comment: The description is confusing.  What is the expected output?  What is `splitname`?

Comment: hi, the expected output is the simpsons data.frame with "first name, last name" when running the code that's what appears, however there are large spaces between the names outside the ",e.g."Ned Flanders"         "Homer Simpson"

Comment: Can you check the solution below?  (it is based on `sub`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to rearrange the first name followed by last name, we could use `sub`.  We capture one or more than character which is not a `,` in a group, followed by `,` followed by 0 or more space (`\\s*`), capture one or more characters that are not a `,` as the 2nd group, and in the replacement reverse the backreference to get the output.

```
sub("([^,]+),\\s*([^,]+)", "\\2 \\1", simpsons)
#[1] "Moe Syzlak"           "C. Montgomery Burns"  "Rev. Timothy Lovejoy" "Ned Flanders"         "Homer Simpson"        "Dr. Julius Hibbert"
```

Comment: trying to remove the spaces between "Moe Syzlak" and "C.Montgomery Burns" and "Ned Flanders" and "Homer Simpson"

Comment: @danielhong Do you need `MoeSyzlak`, `C.MontgomeryBurns` etc?

Comment: yes, both return the results but there appears to be a large space preceding the names that were originally arranged with the last name first.

Comment: @danielhong Did the solution above solved your problem?